# Should I declare a number as constant if it is passed as a parameter to a meaningful named function?

Tags: maintainability, software-quality, magic-numbers, code-maintainability

Suppose we a validation code similar to the following:

```
Rule(account => account.CompanyName).MaxLength(50)
```

Or

```
Rule(account => account.Balance).MustBeGreaterThan(0)
```

Do we still call the numbers 50 or 0 a magic number and define a constant for it, although the functions those are passed in have meaningful name which explains what the number is for?